# Android: Adding multiple instances of the same image

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an app for circuits. The main screen is basically where there circuits will be designed using several components. To select the components, there is a button that takes the user to a next activity. This activity shows all the components that you can choose. So I have two activity classes and one Surface View class. The main activity class is called CircuitDesigner and it is set to contentview set to surfaceview class called GameView. The second activity class is called Gates.

So for example from the gates class if i choose an "And" gate component, i will be taken back to the main activity and i can place the gate there. Although this is working using the following code. I want to how to add multiple and gates. So everytime i click the "and" gate button i can add one and gate. Just like a tower defense game where you can add multiple towers on the screen.

Also just to let you know, if this is a stupid question, well bear with me as I am just learning all this at the moment.

Their code is as follows

```
public class CircuitDesigner extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener{

    GameView Gameview;
    float x, y;
    boolean and = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Gameview = new GameView (this);
        FrameLayout Game = new FrameLayout(this);
        Gameview.setOnTouchListener(this);

        x=0;
    y=0;


        LinearLayout GameWidgets = new LinearLayout (this);

        Button AndGate = new Button(this);
        TextView MyText = new TextView(this);

        AndGate.setWidth(300);
        AndGate.setText("AndGate");
        MyText.setText("rIZ..i");

        GameWidgets.addView(MyText);
        GameWidgets.addView(AndGate); 

        Game.addView(Gameview);
        Game.addView(GameWidgets);

        setContentView(Game);
        AndGate.setOnClickListener(this);


}
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Gates.class);
    i.putExtra("circuit", "and");
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    // re-starts this activity from game-view. add this.finish(); to remove from stack
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("andInfo")){
        and = true;
    }

}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Gameview.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Gameview.resume();
}



public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Thread ourThread = null;
boolean isRunning = false;


public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    ourHolder = getHolder();
}

public void pause(){
    isRunning = false;
    while(true){
        try {
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread = null;
}

public void resume(){
    isRunning = true;
    ourThread = new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();
}
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

        if(x != 0 && y != 0 && and == true){
            Bitmap test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            canvas.drawBitmap(test, x-(test.getWidth()/2), y-(test.getHeight()/2), null);

        }
        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

}


}
}
```

And the Gates Class is

```
public class Gates extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button bAnd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gates);
    bAnd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAnd);

    bAnd.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String msg = i.getStringExtra("circuit");

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bAnd:
        i.putExtra("andInfo", "and");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just directly use Drawables. if your get a drawable with getResources().getDrawable(int resid) the system will not allocate a new Bitmap every time. It will instead optimize it and re-use always the same bitmap.